# LetsEncrypt with Apache2 Redirect

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, lets-encrypt, apache2.4

I have been asked to setup a Vhost (Domain#2) that needs its own block but points to the same directory as another Vhost (Domain#1).  I am using Chef to automate LetsEncrypt's challenge requests and SSL setup.

Currently when LetsEncrypt attempts to get its generated challenge file it will try to get it from the directory of Domain#2, which doesn't exist.  (ie:  Domain#2/.well-known/acme-challenge/)  Naturally this throws an invalid response of 404.

I notice when it gets the invalid response it cleans up the generated challenges it made in Domain#1's /.well-known/acme-challenge directory.

I wrote this Redirect block for the Vhost from what I was able to find online, but it still throws 404 and I am not 100% sure why.  (I have not ever used Redirect or its regex like style before)

What would be the proper way to get this working now?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^tc.DOMAIN#2.com$
RewriteRule ^(?!\.well-known(?:$|/)).* http://tc.DOMAIN#2.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm in the same situation and have been disabling the .htaccess once every 3 months :S